# The best design for a command-line tool

Tags: c++, design-patterns, command-line-tool

It's a simple task, let me briefly describe it!

I'm supposed to code a command-line tool that takes a file-name as an argument, the file
that I'm gonna read consists of lines, each line supposed to be a *command* to execute, the command is followed by it's appropriate arguments to apply on, to make it clear:

```
FILE

sum; 1, 2, 3, 4

Output

10
```

The command-line tool should satisfy those requirements:

1- Easily maintained, **developed** (more *commands* might be added in the future) and user-friendly.

2- Command line arguments might be modified and new could be added.

3- Can live as an open-source project, an organised source-tree.

I'm expecting developers to deal with the source-code and fairly understand it.

I'm a newbie in those stuff, I'm kinda new to design patterns so I don't know much, I wanna follow the best practices in developing this program, I really wanna use design patterns if applicable and make my code better and cleaner, so please advise and guide me to write this tool in the best possible way, I don't wanna write dirty code, I wanna write a high-quality code that does what it's intended to and could be easily developed further.

Please advise and feel free to criticize what I've just said.

**One last thing, I'll be using C++!**

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't so much about "writing a parser" as you think as designing an interpreter for a language, which isn't a very trivial matter. You may wanna look into what a "lexer" and a "parser" are. Flex + Bison are a toolset for C to generate both automagically, for C++ you can look into Boost.Spirit.

Comment: To criticize what you just said: What you need is to hire a programmer, which is not what this website is for. This website, by contrast, is for people who write their own code, have already made a lot of effort, done research, and have come across a specific obstacle, which they demonstrate with a short, minimal, self-contained piece of example code.

Comment: I know what a parser is, it's not eligible here as commands could be easily modified and it's not a good way to modify the source-code.

Comment: For 2), does the main program need to be rebuilt or do you expect plugin-like architecture?

Comment: rebuilt, there will be a source control.

Comment: @KerrekSB the idea is I'm learning and this is an obstacle I'm facing, the design stage, I guess it's a real and important step.

Comment: What about delimeters `;`, `,`? Do those separate arguments or are those passed to commands as is? I mean why not just `"sum this" 1 2 3 4`? Or... how can I pass a comma or have a command ending with semicolon?

Comment: It's a way in differentiating between the command and the arguments, and also the arguments themselves, if I used a parser adding a new command will require me replacing an old code.

Comment: I meant could you have all commands as independent programs and just call `system()` from the main one? Otherwise you'd have to parse lines instead of blindly passing them. Keep it simple.

Comment: @AhmedJolani: That *is* an important step, but this website is not very well suited for that sort of questions, I believe.

Comment: @KerrekSB shall it be moved to [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @mlt: Yeah, that sounds better. Or maybe codereview, if there's a bit more substance.

Answer (score 0):

1- [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/libs/program_options/) is your friend when it comes to parsing command line options.
2- Take a look at the [**command pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Although it is easier to implement in language that has reflection facilities, it is still possible to have a map of "command strings" mapped to function. Please use C++11 facilities for this. i.e. std::function.
3- There is no standard structure for C++ projects. Personally, I use Boost's recommended structure.